# How to track frequency of multiple randbetween() outcomes in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I am attempting to simulate a large quantity of dice rolls using Excel or LibreOffice Calc. I managed to find  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1278252/how-to-use-randbetween-x-times-in-a-single-formula?newreg=b74585aea98045b6a0e1d1c5b1a9ef66) a formula to generate multiple random numbers based on values specifying how many numbers to generate and number generation range, and then adds the total:

`=SUM(RANDBETWEEN(1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,$A2))<=$A2)*$B2))`

Rather than calculating the sum of the 'dice' as this does, what I'm trying to do is get an output showing how many times the a specific outcome occurs, e.g. how often a 1 is rolled.

While I know how to use the various count functions to do this if I were trying to determine the frequency of a value occurring in a column or row of cells, I can't figure out how to do this for the set of numbers generated within that single cell.

Is this even possible?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit for (hopefully) further clarity:

So, for example, the function above produces an outcome like this:

[image]

It allows me to specify a number of dice to roll (at A2) and the number of sides on the dice (at B2) (the picture also includes a constant modifier, but I'm not concerned with that here), and then in a single cell (E1 in the image) it generates multiple random numbers within those parameters and list the sum of them all.  So, in the image, it generated 2 numbers between 1 and 3, and added constant modifier of two, resulting in 7.

What I am trying to figure out is how to have the E1 cell output indicate the how many times a specific value was generated.  So, in the example, in order to get that output of 7, the two randomly generated numbers had to have been 2 and 3. What I am hoping to do is figure out a way to specify I want E1's output to equal how often a 3 was generated, so that in the example the E1 cell would read 1.

---

Edit2:
So when I enter a #dice and #sides value, the function as currently written generates several random numbers between 1 and the #sides value, and outputs their sum.  If the #dice value is 3, it generates 3 random numbers and gives the sum of those three numbers.  If I change the #dice value to 10, it generates 10 random numbers and gives the sum of those.  At no point do I see the randomly generated numbers, only the sum.

I am not interested in the sum of the random numbers.  Instead, what I am hoping to do is change the function so it tracks how often a specific number is generated when it generates the random numbers.

So, for example, let's say the #dice is 4 and the #sides is 6, and function then generates this set of numbers:  1, 3, 5, 1.  The solution I'm hoping for would count that a 1 was generated 2 times, and the output of the function would be 2.  If it generated a set of 4, 5, 1, 3, the output would be 1.  A set of 1, 1, 1, 2 would have an output of 3.

Like the current function, the solution I'm hoping to find does not actually show me the randomly generated numbers, only the final output - the number of times a 1 was generated.  Just as single cell array formula to track how often ones are generated.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by a set of numbers generated within a single cell, and how you want to use it.  Can you provide some sample date (mock-up or screenshot), and what results you want from that sample data?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  Edited to hopefully better explain what I'm looking for.

Comment: There won't always be a single answer to this, there may be a number of correct answers. For example if you had a 4 sided dice in your example and the answer was 7  with a modifier of 2, any of the following would be correct 1,4 | 4,1 | 2,3 | 3,2. How do you want to account for this?

Comment: The direction you want to go with this is clearer, but it's very vague and ambiguous.  It will be hard for people to actually nail down a specific requirement to address (or what gets addressed won't really cover what you want).  Can you make the requirements more explicit (comprehensively define exactly what would be a successful solution)?

Comment: Apologies for ambiguity - I am out of my depth here, but hopefully this edit clarifies things.

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  Figured it out!  Thanks for your time

Comment: erk.. err.. would you mind sharing the answer..(for the benefit of the future readers.. & to remove this question from "unanswered" list) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=COUNTIF(RANDBETWEEN(1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,$A2))<=$A2)*$B2), 1)

So this does what I was looking for.  The latter COUNTIF condition can be changed as well, so for example instead tracking how often 1 occurs, by entering "<=2" as the last condition, the cell will output the total number of ones or twos that are rolled.

edit:  On further testing, this seems to produce an error when only generating 1 random number.  So clearly it's not a perfect solution, but good enough for my purposes.